# Numeric value with wild card or regular expression in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, select

I need to search using wild card or any regular expression that fetch the data having numeric value like , In database I have data like-

```
2gsoft,web6, netsoft, soft2soft , softtech etc.
```

And I am using REGEXP `'^[0-9].'`

but its fetching only `2gsoft`. I need to fetch data having numeric value whether in last or first or in middle.

Comment: Get rid of the hat `^` so that `[0-9]` from anywhere in the subject string is matched.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

`^` - Means match in the beginning of string

[MySQL Regexps](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot . I was using '[0-9]' with wildcard but now with REGEXP its working. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Is there any other way that search if there is .(dot) in database

Answer (score 0):

Use [**REGEXP()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) function

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '[[:digit:]]';
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '[0-9]';
```